# javascript returning 404 error and uncaught reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cesiumjs

[image]I got a code where it labels the globe, the problem is that when I try to run it in the local server it is giving me a 404 error and uncaught reference error. The code is as below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    @import url(bucket.css);
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="require.js" data-main="main"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cesiumContainer" class="fullSize"></div>
<div id="loadingOverlay"><h1>Loading...</h1></div>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<script>
require(['Cesium', 'Button'], function(Cesium, Button)
{
    "use strict";

    function addLabel(scene, ellipsoid) {
        Sandcastle.declare(addLabel);   // For highlighting in Sandcastle.
        var labels = new Cesium.LabelCollection();
        labels.add({
            position : ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(-75.10, 39.57)),
            text     : 'Philadelphia'
        });
        scene.getPrimitives().add(labels);
    }

    function setLabelFont(scene, ellipsoid) {
        Sandcastle.declare(setLabelFont);   // For highlighting in Sandcastle.
        var labels = new Cesium.LabelCollection();
        labels.add({
            position  : ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(-75.10, 39.57)),
            text      : 'Philadelphia',
            // CSS font-family
            font      : '24px Helvetica',
            fillColor : { red : 0.0, blue : 1.0, green : 1.0, alpha : 1.0 },
            outlineColor : { red : 0.0, blue : 0.0, green : 0.0, alpha : 1.0 },
            outlineWidth : 2,
            style : Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL_AND_OUTLINE
        });
        scene.getPrimitives().add(labels);
    }

    function setLabelProperties(scene, ellipsoid) {
        Sandcastle.declare(setLabelProperties); // For highlighting in Sandcastle.
        var labels = new Cesium.LabelCollection();
        var l = labels.add({
            position : ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(-75.10, 39.57)),
            text     : 'Philadelphia'
        });

        l.setPosition(ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(-75.10, 39.57, 300000.0)));
        l.setScale(2.0);
        scene.getPrimitives().add(labels);
    }

    function addLabelsInReferenceFrame(scene, ellipsoid) {
        Sandcastle.declare(addLabelsInReferenceFrame);  // For highlighting in Sandcastle.
        var center = ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(-75.59777, 40.03883));
        var labels = new Cesium.LabelCollection(undefined);
        labels.modelMatrix = Cesium.Transforms.eastNorthUpToFixedFrame(center);
        labels.add({
            position : new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            text     : 'Center'
        });
        labels.add({
            position : new Cesium.Cartesian3(1000000.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            text     : 'East'
        });
        labels.add({
            position : new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 1000000.0, 0.0),
            text     : 'North'
        });
        labels.add({
            position : new Cesium.Cartesian3(0.0, 0.0, 1000000.0),
            text     : 'Up'
        });
        scene.getPrimitives().add(labels);
    }

    function createButtons(widget) {
        var ellipsoid = widget.centralBody.getEllipsoid();
        var scene = widget.scene;
        var primitives = scene.getPrimitives();

        new Button({
            label: 'Add label',
            onClick: function() {
                primitives.removeAll();
                addLabel(scene, ellipsoid);
                Sandcastle.highlight(addLabel);
            }
        }).placeAt('toolbar');

        new Button({
            label: 'Set font',
            onClick: function() {
                primitives.removeAll();
                setLabelFont(scene, ellipsoid);
                Sandcastle.highlight(setLabelFont);
            }
        }).placeAt('toolbar');

        new Button({
            label: 'Set properties',
            onClick: function() {
                primitives.removeAll();
                setLabelProperties(scene, ellipsoid);
                Sandcastle.highlight(setLabelProperties);
            }
        }).placeAt('toolbar');

        new Button({
            label: 'Add labels in reference frame',
            onClick: function() {
                primitives.removeAll();
                addLabelsInReferenceFrame(scene, ellipsoid);
                Sandcastle.highlight(addLabelsInReferenceFrame);
            }
        }).placeAt('toolbar');
    }

    var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');

    createButtons(widget);
    addLabel(widget.scene, widget.centralBody.getEllipsoid());

    Sandcastle.finishedLoading();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The error am getting is as follows:

1) `GET http://localhost/Source/Widgets/CesiumWidget/CesiumWidget.css 404 (Not Found)`

```
2) Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I do not understand where the CesiumWidget.css file is being invoked in the code. So it would be a lot helpful if someone can guide me.

I tried adding the require js . But now its giving me one more error.

3) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Check the image, why am i getting that error in that line. The error which its showing is no way related to whats written in the line.

Comment: You didn't include `require js`. You can read in this link for more info: [http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html)

Comment: means? i just i need to include the require js?

Comment: @vher2 I tried revising the code as u mentioned. But including the require js file just caused one more error. Please check the revised edits.

Comment: Is your #2 error still occurs? If it does then your require.js not loaded or not found on your server. Do you have `main.js`. As mentioned in the docs: `data-main attribute tells require.js to load main.js after require.js loads.`

Comment: but i don't need to load a seperate js file. I thought i will include all the required file in the html file only. Can't that be done and still include require.js

Answer (score 1):

2) I had the same problem. The fact is that you do not have to copy-and-paste exactly the examples given in the Sandcastle livecoding interface.
You should :

- import Cesium.js and Sandcastle in the head script:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Cesium_root/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Cesium_root/Apps/Sandcastle/Sandcastle-header.js"></script>
  ```

  `Cesium_root` can be whether a local or a remote location, but I suggest you to install Cesium on your server if you start using it a lot.
- just put in your body script the code between braces, from `"use script;"` to `Sandcastle.finishedLoading();`

1) It is bucket.css that imports the missing css because it uses it in order to display the Cesium widget. Sandcastle is just an overlay. The 2) should solve this problem as well, beacause bucket.css will look for it starting from the Cesium_root you gave him in the head. Provided, of course, that bucket.css is at his correct location, that is: `Cesium_root/Apps/Sandcastle/templates`. You should correct it in the html head.

3) I also had this error, I suppose it was solved by 2) if I am not mistaking.

Hope I was clear enough and that it will work for you.